# Switching windows with CMD + TAB - Mac OS X Developer

Tags: java, macos, jar, jframe

Hi so I'm creating a program in Java and I want to prevent the Java icon, that always pops up whenver a .jar file / class is executed, to stop popping up. I have seen many applications where this window exists and cannot be accessed by CMD+TAB. The application I am making doesn't have a active visible window.

[image: CMD+TAB Window]

For those interested in what this is for:

The application is a background application that performs customised tasks for me, like executing bash or moving files. Its an attempt to create a more featured spotlight that does personal tasks for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Early in your `main()` method, include this:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```